# Orchestrated vs Choreographed Service-Oriented Architecture in large scale?

Tags: web-services, service, architecture, soa, orchestration

I'm an architect in a large scale financial company and we are in the beginning of implementing a new business oriented infosystem across our different countries.

From the very early on the core idea has been to follow microservice oriented principles as much as possible *(and making sure engineers have read Building Microservices book by Sam Newman)*.

By now I've come to crossroads. Our services are primarily JSON REST services using Swagger for automated documentation, but in order to use these services in our business processes and making sure not to write business logic into services outside the domain of those services, we've been using Camunda as an orchestration tool. And Camunda is fine *(though some have considered Corezoid as an alternative)*, but somewhat clumsy in what is an otherwise an elegant set of services.

Now service orchestration is a concept pretty familiar to most engineers. But it is one that I am not entirely happy with due to still having a central engine that drives everything. It is incredibly expensive to replace later down the road *(though still cheaper to replace than a monolith)*. And even if this central engine is split into multiple engines *(which is actually the case today)*, it does not necessarily make it much better.

In recent years there has been a movement with microservices towards choreographed *(close to event-driven)* architecture. It is at this point where I am looking for advice from engineers and architects who have faced similar crossroad decision points.

I absolutely love the idea of decoupled architecture and despite feeling good about killing monoliths and having elegant independent services, I still detect a lot of dependencies in business process as a whole in current orchestrated solution in where it should not actually exist.

And it's not like we are avoiding events. We have actually implemented events on our architecture as well in order to decouple many processes with the core principle that if you don't need a synchronized response and just need to notify of something happening to initiate another process an event is put up that may be caught by another process that starts executing. And orchestration is easier to explain and visualize, it is easier to tweak and modify by more technical minded business users. And I think it is easier to test and validate from business perspective. Orchestrated architecture like this also *(usually)* expects a good service discovery and quality automated documentation and non-functional requirements which are all things I value greatly.

All of those things that are a question to me in choreographed approach since I don't have first-hand experience in running this in large scale - just some local test prototypes.

But I think you see where I am coming from. I'm trying to consider alternatives without having to regret driving the company all the other way in the end.

Perhaps you can share your own experience with a similar situation or share an interesting link or two? Or am I looking for a silver bullet that doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services need to interact  - services that don't interact are not part of the same system. The search needs access to the catalog, the cart doesn't get the price info from the page, the account needs the purchase history, the recommender needs purchase history, the cart needs to verify the currently available coupons, the inventory needs to know something was purchased etc.

Service boundaries are set to minimize the needed interactions. It can make sense to cut a service to smaller components but if they share a database (internal structure) they are [different aspects of the service](http://arnon.me/2017/03/services-aspects/).

When services interact it creates a level of coupling - at the least, this coupling is some API (JSON or otherwise) that the service has to "maintain" for so other services can interact with it.

Another coupling type is temporal coupling - which is what you get in request-reply situations (and you can eliminate in event driven systems) However, Orchestration vs. Choreography is not about these differences (even though orchestration is mostly associated with request/reply) - it is about central control and governance  vs.flexibility and serendipity.

Orchestration has risks like migrating business logic out of services into the orchestration while choreography runs the risk of chaos. By the way, direct request/reply integration has the worst of both worlds but wins on simplicity when systems are small enough.

Choosing between the two is a balancing act (like most architectural decisions) for instance, Netflix built on choreography for a lot of time but then found they need some control back and [introduced an orchestration engine](https://github.com/Netflix/conductor). Nothing is a silver bullet :)

Personally, I like choreography better because of the reduced coupling and flexibility and favor tools like [open Zipkin](http://zipkin.io) to bring some order into the chaos.

You can see a partial example for an orchestration based arch in [slides 10-22 of a presentation I did about microservices](https://www.slideshare.net/arnonrgo/microservices-past-and-future-its-dj-vu-all-over-again)

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand where you're coming from, having recently redesigned a system to a "microservices" architecture. I like (and use) the approach by these guys: http://scs-architecture.org/

The main point is, that you try to avoid cross-dependencies between you "services", which basically makes choreography obsolete. The hard part is decomposing your problem domain into chunks which do not need eachother for any of the executed business-cases. They may need different kinds of data that may or may not be "shared", as in present in multiple systems, but they don't need synchronous calls between them for any given business case.

This is quite different from what Netflix is doing for example. Those guys/gals are doing chain-calling through different layers of services, each adding its logic to the "process". This model might fit in some cases, and probably fits in Netflix's case. But it may not be necessary for you.

The ideal Self-Contained System would be completely independent of other Self-Contained Systems, would cover one or more highly cohesive *business functions* (in full depth from the UI to Persistence!), and would be not calling any other system synchronously. The ideal system would let the client "orchestrate", by just offering links through its Web (HTML) interface.

Think more like Amazon. The "Landing Page" is a different application than the "Search", which is still different from the "Checkout". They are completely different, sometimes even look a bit different! Integrated by links and forms in HTML, not explicitly orchestrated.

This might be what you are looking for.

Some warnings: First instinct of some people is to have "Customer" microservice, or "Product Repository" microservice, and similar. This will not lead to Self-Contained Systems, as you will need synchronous calls to these things, making them essentially "central" components. The key is to split the business domain, so bounded contexts a la Eric Evans.

Comment: I really like your reply and it is giving me a lot to think about. If you have any further articles or book ideas to share, I'm open to them as well :)

Comment: I found this presentation from Stefan Tilkov cool https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pU1gXA0rfwc, also his colleague Eberhard Wolff on the same subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXbHdF7p1X4. And of course the DDD book from Eric Evans, at least Chapter 14 (about bounded contexts) might be interesting for you.